# Pulling CME data with Python & BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I would like to pull a select list of symbols with the associated prices for that symbol from the CME website below. I'm able to get a list of symbols, but I haven't been able to figure out how to pull the prices in each row.

Having trouble when using 'Inspect' on a browser the tags to query other than 'span'. Thoughts to get me past this problem?

Code:

```
import urllib
from requests import get
from requests.exceptions import RequestException
from contextlib import closing
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def simple_get(url):
    """
    Attempts to get the content at `url` by making an HTTP GET request.
    If the content-type of response is some kind of HTML/XML, return the
    text content, otherwise return None.
    """
    try:
        with closing(get(url, stream=True)) as resp:
            if is_good_response(resp):
                return resp.content
            else:
                return None

    except RequestException as e:
        log_error('Error during requests to {0} : {1}'.format(url, str(e)))
        return None

def is_good_response(resp):
    """
    Returns True if the response seems to be HTML, False otherwise.
    """
    content_type = resp.headers['Content-Type'].lower()
    return (resp.status_code == 200 
            and content_type is not None 
            and content_type.find('html') > -1)

def log_error(e):
    print(e)

raw_html = simple_get('https://www.cmegroup.com/trading/price-limits.html#equityIndex')
html = BeautifulSoup(raw_html, 'html.parser', store_line_numbers=True)
seq = ['ESM0', 'NQM0', 'RTYM0', 'YMM0'] 

for quote in html.find_all('span'):
    symbolcme = quote.get_text(strip=True)
    #print("Check Symbol: ", symbolcme)
    for text in seq:
        if text in symbolcme: 
            print(quote.sourceline, ' Symbol:', symbolcme)
```

Results:

```
2014  Symbol: E-mini S&P 500 Futures (ESM0)
2047  Symbol: E-mini Nasdaq-100 Futures (NQM0)
2065  Symbol: E-mini Dow ($5) Futures (YMM0)
2392  Symbol: E-mini  Russell 2000 Index Futures (RTYM0)
2500  Symbol: Micro E-mini Dow Jones Industrial Average Index Futures (MYMM0)
2515  Symbol: Micro E-mini Nasdaq-100 Index Futures (MNQM0)
2551  Symbol: Micro E-mini S&P 500 Index Futures (MESM0)
```

Comment: Do you have a specific technical question? Stack Overflow is not a substitute for guides, tutorials or documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BeautifulSoup's [`tag.parent`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#parent) and [`tag.next_siblings`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-siblings-and-previous-siblings) work together well here, assuming you wanted the prices in the same row as the Quotes that were printed.

```py
for quote in html.find_all('span'):
    symbolcme = quote.get_text(strip=True)
    for text in seq:
        if text in symbolcme:
            print(quote.sourceline, ' Symbol:', symbolcme)
            prices = [sibling.get_text() for sibling in quote.parent.next_siblings]
            print(prices)
```

Output:

```
2015  Symbol: E-mini S&P 500 Futures (ESM0)
['240000', '252000 / 228000', '223150', '208700', '191850']
2048  Symbol: E-mini Nasdaq-100 Futures (NQM0)
['726475', '762900 / 690050', '675475', '631725', '580725']
2066  Symbol: E-mini Dow ($5) Futures (YMM0)
['19951', '20955 / 18947', '18545', '17340', '15934']
2393  Symbol: E-mini  Russell 2000 Index Futures (RTYM0)
['104070', '109360 / 98780', '96660', '90310', '82900']
```

Comment: Had a feeling it had something to do with .next_siblings. Just couldn't get it figured out. Thank you

Comment: @MikeC Nice to know that this worked out for you. If the solution was correct, could you click the check mark next to the answer? This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.